# Add DEFAULT CONSTRAINT at the end of a CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql-server, default

How can I add a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT at the end of a CREATE TABLE?

I would like to have an independent line at the end like

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  table_id       INT NOT NULL,
  firstColumn    NVARCHAR(10),
  secondColumn   INT,
  thirdColumn    INT,
  CONSTRAINT DEF_secColumn DEFAULT 0 FOR secondColumn
)
```

It's not working. I get the error message

> Incorrect syntax near 'for'.

May you can help me? Thanks a lot in forward!

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql), that form is not supported for default constraints. It is supported for every other column constraint, just not `DEFAULT`. Why? That's not a question you can really ask with T-SQL, it just is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use default next to the field you need the default value for, e.g :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  table_id       INT NOT NULL,
  firstColumn    NVARCHAR(10),
  secondColumn   INT DEFAULT 0,
  thirdColumn    INT
)
```

Or if you really want to add the constraint, you can add it later with the `ALTER TABLE` :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  table_id       INT NOT NULL,
  firstColumn    NVARCHAR(10),
  secondColumn   INT,
  thirdColumn    INT
)

ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT DEF_secColumn DEFAULT 0 FOR [secondColumn]
```

Or 3rd option as suggested by @jeroen-mostert

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  table_id       INT NOT NULL,
  firstColumn    NVARCHAR(10),
  secondColumn   INT CONSTRAINT DEF_secColumn DEFAULT 0,
  thirdColumn    INT
)
```

Comment: You're missing one more syntax option, which is to add the name in the first instance: `secondColumn INT CONSTRAINT DEF_secColumn DEFAULT 0`.

Comment: Haven't thought of that one, I'll add it in the edit, thanks.